# How programming languages are storing arrays

Tags: assembly, compilation, processor

When I want to evaluate some expression, let's say:
`2*5` program stores `2` and `5` in registers and then performs `MUL` operation. But what if we want to multiply huge arrays:

```
a = [1, ....... , 100000]
b = [1, ....... , 100000]
a * b
```

Do we need to generate asm which will load and multiply elements one-by-one or is it possible to store whole vectors in some kind of registers?
I know that there is `Advanced Vector Extensions (AVX)` which allows to store bigger vectors in registers but still, it has very limited size.
I'm not asking about any particular language or processor, just for overall idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiply": element by element, dot product, or cross product?

Comment: It's just an example. It can be dot product.

Comment: Some architectures have vector coprocessors (e.g. Cray) and many modern CPUs have support for short vectors (SIMD), but in the general case you need a loop to iterate over your arrays processing one element per iteration.

Comment: Since you're saying your question isn't for any particular language or processor, then the answer is: it could be any of the options you suggest depending upon the language and the processor. :)

Answer (score 1):

Except in very, very specific circumstances (i.e., [vector processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_processor), which are mostly used in supercomputers, such as the [Cray X1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray_X1)) no processor has registers that will support loading such large arrays.

As was mentioned, many CPUs could use SIMD, but again, these are usually made for specific usages (for instance, Graphics Processor Units use built in SIMD systems to process all the data required), and nearly always require hand coding the system in an assembly language.

[Vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization) might be an area of interest to you, as it concerns compilers (mainly for C/C++, I believe) that attempt to compile traditional code with loops into optimized assembly code using vectors. Unfortunately, this usually deals with vectors much smaller than the 100,000 items you asked about.

**Tl;dr**: Nope, that large of registers don't exist, nor do languages/compilers that readily support them. But there are several, smaller scale solutions that might interest you!

Hope this is helpful!